# Encryption plus Compression

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to encrypt and compress my client<->server communication efficiently. 
My idea is to let the client use a key for the encryption. 
The key shall be defined by the client during registration.

So my difficulty is to find a encryption way 
that allows nearly any String to work as key 
and to find an compressing method that works well with encryption.

And on top of that I don't even know if its possible to encrypt and compress
my current communication 
that is based on Serialized Objects.

Has anyone an idea how to accomplish this? Or suggestions/replacement for that?

Comment: What is the communication protocol between the server and the client ?

Comment: Stream so iit should be TCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message needs to be compressed prior to encryption since encrypted data can not be compressed. Simply use zip compression.

If you have no control over the password use a key derivation function such as PBKDF2 to create a secure key from the password.

But probably the simplest and most secure method is to use HTTPS to provide the encryption of the data in-transit.

If the client and server supports it add zip encoding to the header:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

See [HTTP compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression), note the security implications.